# Toggling Map layers visibility from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, leaflet

First of all, I am design student and I use Vue.js for prototyping my senior project. So this is not real working project. Just prototype of some diary app.

My issue is, I build a map component via [Vue2Leaflet](https://github.com/KoRiGaN/Vue2Leaflet) which has Tile Layer.

Over the Tile Layer I rendered a GeoJSON file which has two objects of coordinates.

I have also a datepicker component which emits values by an EventBus.

My aim is: when datepicker emits a specific value, turning off an `<l-geo-json>` and turn on the other `<l-geo-json>`.

`<l-geo-json>` has a parameter which is `:visible` to show or hide. `:visible` gets parameter from GeoJSON object. `datepicker` emits some boolean value for changing GeoJSON parameter. GeoJSON parameter changes but it does not render in map.

I think, it is because of not re-rendering map component.

My map component is like:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="refresh" id="MapView2">
    <i class="material-icons geoLocate" v-on:click="geoLoc">location_searching</i>
    <l-map :zoom="zoom" :options="{ zoomControl: false }" class="map" :center="center">
      <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></l-tile-layer>
      <l-geo-json :visible="yesterday.day" :geojson="bus.geojson" :options="bus.options"></l-geo-json>
      <l-geo-json :visible="today.day" :geojson="today.geojson" :options="today.options"></l-geo-json>
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Vue from 'vue';
import Leaflet from 'leaflet';
import L from 'leaflet';
import { LMap, LTileLayer, LGeoJson } from 'vue2-leaflet';
import PopupContent from './GeoJson2Popup';
import { data, EventBus2 } from '../assets/geojson/sample-geojson.js';


export default {
  name: 'MapView2',
  components: {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer,
    LGeoJson,
  },
  data(){
    return {
      zoom: 13,
      center: {
        lat: '',
        lng: '',
      },
      url:'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/light-v9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=...',
      attribution: '',
      yesterday: {
        geojson: data.yesterday,
        day: data.yesterday.visible,
        options: {
          onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
          color: "#45B8FF",
          fillOpacity: 0.8
        }
      },
      today: {
        geojson: data.today,
        day: data.today.visible,
        options: {
          onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
          color: "#45B8FF",
          fillOpacity: 0.8
        }
      },
    }
  },
  methods: {
    geoLoc() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.position = position.coords;
        this.center.lat = position.coords.latitude
        this.center.lng = position.coords.longitude
        this.zoom = 25
        console.log(position.coords)
      })
    }
  },
  beforeCreate() {
    if(navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
        this.isLoading = false
        this.position = position.coords;
        this.center.lat = position.coords.latitude
        this.center.lng = position.coords.longitude
        console.log(position.coords)
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    EventBus2.$on('mapDay', pickerValue => {
      switch (pickerValue) {
        case data.today.id:
        data.yesterday.visible = true;
        data.today.visible = false;
        break;
        case data.yesterday.id:
        data.yesterday.visible = false;
        data.today.visible = true;
        break;
      }
    });
  },
};
</script>
```

And also my geojson.js file is like

```
    import Vue from 'vue';
    export const EventBus2 = new Vue();
    export const data = {
      today: {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "id": "0520",
        "visible": false,
        "features": [ // geojson features and coordinates ]
      },

      yesterday: {
        "type": "FeatureCollection",
        "id": "0520",
        "visible": false,
        "features": [ // geojson features and coordinates ]
      }
  }
```

As you can see, datepicker emit some value in `MMDD` format. Switch statement checks value in GeoJSON data by `id`. If it matches, change `visible` property. It is actually changed when datepicker emits.

But it is not render in map (the GeoJSON layers do not change visibility accordingly).

How can I do this? Should I use `watch` or something like that? If it is, how can I use that?

Comment: watch geojson in component ·l-geo-json· when value changed,you should do refresh yourself

Comment: @jacky how can I implement the watch part. Actually I am not a developer, I am just a confused design student who has sharp deadline :/

Answer (score 2):

You should simply directly change your instance `data`.

For clarity I will do as if you imported from your `geojson.js` file as `data2`. Calling both the same might be a reason why you are confused.

```js
import { data as data2, EventBus2 } from '../assets/geojson/sample-geojson.js';
```

The reason why your GeoJSON layers visibility does not dynamically change is because you properly initialize your instance `data` and `day` properties using information from your `data2`, but that does not dynamically bind them to future modifications in `data2`.

Therefore the easiest approach would be to toggle your instance `data` and `day` properties in your `"mapDay"` event listener, instead of the information in `data2`.

```js
EventBus2.$on('mapDay', pickerValue => {
  switch (pickerValue) {
    case data2.today.id:
      this.yesterday.day = true;
      this.today.day = false;
    break;
    case data2.dun.id:
      this.yesterday.day = false;
      this.today.day = true;
    break;
  }
});
```

You could also toggle both your `data` and `data2`, in case you want `data2` to also be synced, e.g. if you use it in another component. Note that such a strategy would be brittle, since changing `data2` in that other component would have no effect here.

On the other hand, you could simplify your visibility toggling logic by simply storing your `pickerValue` in your instance `data`, and compare it to your `geojson.id` within `:visible` attribute binding expression: `:visible="pickerValue === yesterday.geojson.id"`

Code example:

```js
Vue.component('map-view-2', {
  template: '#map-view-2',
  components: {
    'l-map': Vue2Leaflet.LMap,
    'l-tile-layer': Vue2Leaflet.LTileLayer,
    'l-geo-json': Vue2Leaflet.LGeoJson,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      pickerValue: '0520',
      url: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      yesterday: {
        geojson: data2.yesterday,
      },
      today: {
        geojson: data2.today,
      },
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('mapDay', pickerValue => {
      this.pickerValue = pickerValue;
    });
  },
});

// Dummy DatePicker component for the sake of the demo.
Vue.component('date-picker', {
  template: '#datepicker',
  methods: {
    handleInputChange(event) {
      this.$root.$emit('mapDay', event.target.value);
    },
  },
});

const data2 = {
  today: {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "id": "0520",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [2.34, 48.86] // Left
      },
    }],
  },
  yesterday: {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "id": "0519",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [2.35, 48.86] // Right
      },
    }],
  },
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue2-leaflet@1.0.2/dist/vue2-leaflet.js"></script>

<template id="map-view-2">
  <div id="MapView2">
    <l-map :zoom="11" style="height: 100px;" :center="[48.86, 2.35]">
      <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></l-tile-layer>
      <l-geo-json :visible="pickerValue === yesterday.geojson.id" :geojson="yesterday.geojson"></l-geo-json>
      <l-geo-json :visible="pickerValue === today.geojson.id" :geojson="today.geojson"></l-geo-json>
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="datepicker">
  <fieldset @change="handleInputChange">
    <legend>Choose a date</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="date" value="0520" id="today" checked />
    <label for="today">Today 0520</label>
    <input type="radio" name="date" value="0519" id="yesterday" />
    <label for="yesterday">Yesterday 0519</label>
    <input type="radio" name="date" value="none" id="none" />
    <label for="none">None</label>
  </fieldset>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <map-view-2></map-view-2>
  <date-picker></date-picker>
</div>
```

A more modular approach would expose the `pickerValue` data as a `prop`, so that you modify it at the parent (e.g. App) level directly, instead of having to listen to your `"mapDay"` event:

```js
Vue.component('map-view-2', {
  template: '#map-view-2',
  components: {
    'l-map': Vue2Leaflet.LMap,
    'l-tile-layer': Vue2Leaflet.LTileLayer,
    'l-geo-json': Vue2Leaflet.LGeoJson,
  },
  props: {
    // Receive the value directly from parent component / App.
    pickerValue: {
      type: String,
      default: '0520',
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      yesterday: {
        geojson: data2.yesterday,
      },
      today: {
        geojson: data2.today,
      },
    };
  },
});

// Dummy DatePicker component for the sake of the demo.
Vue.component('date-picker', {
  template: '#datepicker',
  props: {
    value: {
      type: String,
      default: '0520',
    },
  },
  methods: {
    handleInputChange(event) {
      // https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model
      this.$emit('input', event.target.value);
    },
  },
});

const data2 = {
  today: {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "id": "0520",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [2.34, 48.86] // Left
      },
    }],
  },
  yesterday: {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "id": "0519",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [2.35, 48.86] // Right
      },
    }],
  },
};

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      pickerValue: '0519', // This value rules child components default value.
    };
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue2-leaflet@1.0.2/dist/vue2-leaflet.js"></script>

<template id="map-view-2">
  <div id="MapView2">
    <l-map :zoom="11" style="height: 100px;" :center="[48.86, 2.35]">
      <l-tile-layer :url="url" :attribution="attribution"></l-tile-layer>
      <l-geo-json :visible="pickerValue === yesterday.geojson.id" :geojson="yesterday.geojson"></l-geo-json>
      <l-geo-json :visible="pickerValue === today.geojson.id" :geojson="today.geojson"></l-geo-json>
    </l-map>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="datepicker">
  <fieldset @change="handleInputChange">
    <legend>Choose a date</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="date" value="0520" id="today" :checked="value === '0520'" />
    <label for="today">Today 0520</label>
    <input type="radio" name="date" value="0519" id="yesterday" :checked="value === '0519'" />
    <label for="yesterday">Yesterday 0519</label>
    <input type="radio" name="date" value="none" id="none" :checked="value === 'none'" />
    <label for="none">None</label>
  </fieldset>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <map-view-2 :picker-value="pickerValue"></map-view-2>
  <date-picker v-model="pickerValue"></date-picker>
</div>
```

All that being said, if your work is only for a design prototype, not even showing off your programming skills, then even Vue, while already quite simple, might be overkill for your task.

Comment: At first, I didn't get your answer but when second time I read your answer, I realized that I write geojson.js wrong in this question. I edited that and maybe there is a change that you can look at again my question. Sorry for that, I wasted your time.

Comment: By the way, I am implemented your answer but I am getting `ReferenceError: data is not defined` and some bunch of `Property or method "foo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.` errors.

Comment: If you did rename your import as `data2`, then obviously you need to rename in your initialization as well: `geojson: data2.yesterday` etc.

Comment: there is a huge mistake I make. But `case.data.dun.id` should be `case data.yesterday.id:` I changed it now but I am really ashamed. Sorry for that.

Comment: I am simplifying components to asking answers in stackoverflow. But sometimes variables names can be confusing. This time I forgot this one, sorry.

Comment: Added some live code examples to show you. That being said, if you are not doing this to demonstrate your programming skills, then even Vue might be overkill for your task.

Comment: You are right but my challenge is demonstrating the user experience to jury. So in my case there should be a datepicker that trigger map layer. Also datepicker triggers some other things. Anyway, at the begining of this project I made a wrong desicion that building this with Vue. But I am really close to deadline and there is nothing to do. So, this example actually is in vue2-leaflet examples. But I couldn't figure it out how to trigger this by my EventBus. At the end, I am thankful to you. You're helped my problematic case.